# Convert DAX to MDX

Tags: ssas, dax, mdx

please can someone tell me what the equivalent of the dax query-->MDX

**calculate( sum([Measures].[Poids Total])  ,ALL([Dim1].[Id Df])))**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At its simplest in MDX it might just be a tuple of the measure and the ALL member of the respective hierarchy:

```
(
  [Measures].[Poids Total],
  [Dim1].[Id Df].[Id Df].[All]
)
```